# Marking the EFI system partition on a USB flash drive as bootable

Tags: partition, usb, startup, efi, bootable-disk

Using only MacOS (no GParted or other Linux utilities), how do I mark the EFI system partition on a USB flash drive as bootable?

1. Insert an empty USB flash drive and launch Disk Utility
2. Erase the drive, choosing the GUID partition scheme
3. Reboot holding down the Alt key

Expected: the USB flash drive should show up as an EFI bootable drive

Actual: no option to EFI boot off the USB flash drive

Now, if I stick that USB flash drive onto a Linux system and use GParted/gnome-disk or similar tool, I can mark the EFI partition as a "System" partition. Now when I put it back into the Mac, the drive shows up in the boot menu. (It won't actually boot since I didn't install a boot loader, but that's not the point -- I need it to show up in the boot menu first.)

I see mention of using fdisk to mark the partition as active, but fdisk is surely only for MBR partition table? I can't find a way to do it with gpt either. Is there anyway to mark the EFI parition as bootable using only MacOS pre-installed utilties?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer, but `bless` might be the tool you're looking for? https://eclecticlight.co/2018/08/30/booting-the-mac-bless-and-what-makes-a-volume-bootable/